# PHP Get last word in URL between / and /

Tags: php, url

How do I get the last word in a url between / and /

For example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/
```

I want to get "extractMe"  (without the quotes) from the url

**NOTE: I need to get the "extractMe" equivilent of the current url.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer to use basename() in these circumstances as it's more implicit.

```
echo basename('http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/'); //extractMe
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex you can match this pattern, or many other more intricate patterns:

```
echo preg_replace('/.*\/(.+?)\/$/','$1',$url);
```

Comment: never use regex with super simpel stuff

Comment: ditto. More words to fill this simpel comment

Comment: For the record, I voted for John, I put this answer to be useful to other people with similar, but not exactly the same problem.

Comment: What do you see is wrong with using basename? it seems to work, although I am guessing it might not on windows server as the slashes will go the other way for paths...

Answer (score 0):

```
$e=explode('/',$url);
echo $e[count($e)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get the **full** path, you can use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$path = trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```